# Solving the equation $f'(x)=-x-xf(x/2)$

Tags: functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am a bit stuck at solving the equation $f'(x)=-x-xf(x/2)$, where $x$ is a real variable.

The argument $x/2$ in $f$ seems a bit hard to overcome.

Could anyone please provide some help?

Comment: It is not that the ODE is not linear: it is not an ODE.

Comment: Of course, it is an ODE, there is only one variable $x$.

Comment: It is not an ODE:  in an ODE the unknown function and its derivatives are evaluated at exactly one point, while in yours you have f evaluated at x/2 and f' evaluated at x. The technical name for such an equation is a *q-difference-differential equation* (in which q is 1/2 or 2, depending on how you look at it

Comment: And it *is* a linear equation: you can immediately check that if f and g are solutions and a and b are two scalars then af+bg is also a solution, and that is what being linear means.

Comment: Oh, I see.. so, it is not solvable?

Comment: I have no idea, the theory of such things is much much much less well known than for ODEs. Someone might come up with a way to solve it, wait a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Let's proceed without thinking.

Let us suppose that $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$ is a solution which is analytic near zero. Then
\begin{align}
  0 = f'(x)+xf(x/2)+x
  &= \sum_{n\geq1}na_nx^{n-1} + \sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{2^n} + x\\
  &= \sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n} + \sum_{n\geq1}a_{n-1}\frac{x^{n}}{2^{n-1}} +x \\
  &= a_1+(2a_2+a_0+1)x+\sum_{n\geq2}\left(a_{n+1}(n+1) + \frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right)x^n
\end{align}
We must then have that $a_1=0$, $a_2=-(1+a_0)/2$ and $$a_{n+1} =- \frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n+1)}$$ for all $n\geq2$. For each choice of $a_0$ there is exactly one solution to these recurrence equations, and it is clear that the series $\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$ does converge, as the coefficients go to zero very very fast.

The odd coefficients are all zero.
OTOH, it is convenient to rewrite the recurrence in the form $$a_{n+2}=-\frac{a_n}{2^n(n+2)},$$ now valid for all $n\geq2$. We see that $$a_{2\cdot2}=a_4 = (-1)\frac{a_2}{2^2\cdot 4}, \quad a_{2\cdot3}=a_6=(-1)^2\frac{a_2}{2^2\cdot 4\cdot 2^3\cdot 6}, \quad a_{2\cdot4}=a_8=(-1)^3\frac{a_2}{2^2\cdot 4\cdot 2^3\cdot 6\cdot 2^4\cdot 8}, \dots$$ and suggests that more generally
$$a_{2n}=(-1)^{n}\frac{1+a_0}{2^{n^2}n!
}$$
This gives you the solutions that are analytic near zero, which are of the form $$a_0+\sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^n\frac{1+a_0}{2^{n^2}n!}x^{2n}
$$

Comment: This shows how Pavel's constant solution $-1$ is special.

Comment: It looks good but I think there must be some minor (?) issues. If you use the $a_{2n}$ you obtained and plot the residual of the equation (using just a few terms in the series), it is not small.

Comment: Yup, the recurrence is correct but the final formula is not. That's what you get from doing math on your phone :-)

Comment: Someone should prove that a solution that is continuous and has a derivative in, say, an interval of the form $(-t,t)$ is analytic there.

Comment: It's fixed! The series converges quite fast. With just 5 terms, and considering $x\in[-1,1]$, the residual is of the order of $10^{-13}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a constant function $f(x)=-1$.